# How can I sum columns using conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do the sum when:

```
 date_ini >= initial_date AND final_date <= date_expired
```

And if it is not in the range will show the last net_insurance from insurances

```
show last_insurance when is not in range
```

Here my tables:

```
   POLICIES
ID  POLICY_NUM     DATE_INI    DATE_EXPIRED   TYPE_MONEY
1,       1234,  "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01"  , 1
2,       5678,  "2013-02-01", "2014-02-01"  , 1
3,       9123,  "2013-03-01", "2014-03-01"  , 1
4,       4567,  "2013-04-01", "2014-04-01"  , 1
5,       8912,  "2013-05-01", "2014-05-01"  , 2
6,       3456,  "2013-06-01", "2014-06-01"  , 2
7,       7891,  "2013-07-01", "2014-07-01"  , 2
8,       2345,  "2013-08-01", "2014-08-01"  , 2

   INSURANCES
 ID POLICY_ID   INITIAL_DATE    FINAL_DATE    NET_INSURANCE
 1,       1,     "2013-01-01",  "2014-01-01",    100
 2,       1,     "2013-01-01",  "2014-01-01",    200
 3,       1,     "2013-01-01",  "2014-01-01",    400
 4,       2,     "2011-01-01",  "2012-01-01",    500
 5,       2,     "2013-01-01",  "2014-01-01",    600
 6,       3,     "2013-01-01",  "2014-01-01",    100
 7,       4,     "2013-01-01",  "2014-01-01",    200
```

I should have

```
    POLICY_NUM   NET
        1234     700
        5678     600
        9123     100
        4567     200
```

Here is what i tried

```
 SELECT  p.policy_num AS policy_num,

 CASE WHEN p.date_ini >= i.initial_date
 THEN SUM(i.net_insurance) 
 ELSE (SELECT max(id) FROM insurances GROUP BY policy_id) END as net

 FROM policies p
 INNER JOIN insurances i ON p.id = i.policy_id AND p.date_ini >= i.initial_date
 GROUP BY p.id
```

Here is my query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6077b/16

Somebody can help me with this please?

Is not working when is not in the range it would show my last_insurance instead of sum

Comment: I don't understand your example.  Every record in `INSURANCES` appears to satisfy the date range criteria, yet you have excluded `ID=5` from the sum for `POLICY_NUM=5678`?  Furthermore, it is clear to me neither what you mean by "*last net_insurance*" (how is *last* determined?), nor when such a value should be used (whenever a record falls outside the range, or only if no in-range records exist for a group?).  Please clarify.

Comment: in insurance  with id 4  "2011-01-01","2012-01-01" is not in the range because in policies "2013-02-01", "2014-02-01" and it should show my last insurance 600 and i'm getting 1100 (the sum)

Comment: Is last_insurance defined by the highest ID or the most recent dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT p.policy_num, SUM(i.net_insurance) net_insurance
  FROM policies p JOIN insurances i 
    ON p.id = i.policy_id
   AND p.date_ini >= i.initial_date
   AND p.date_expired <= i.final_date
 GROUP BY i.policy_id, p.policy_num
UNION ALL
SELECT p.policy_num, i.net_insurance
  FROM
(
  SELECT MAX(i.id) id
    FROM policies p JOIN insurances i 
      ON p.id = i.policy_id
     AND (p.date_ini < i.initial_date
      OR  p.date_expired > i.final_date)
   GROUP BY i.policy_id
) q JOIN insurances i 
    ON q.id = i.id JOIN policies p
    ON i.policy_id = p.id
```

Output:

```
| POLICY_NUM | NET_INSURANCE |
|------------|---------------|
|       1234 |           700 |
|       5678 |           600 |
|       9123 |           100 |
|       4567 |           200 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6077b/43)** demo

Comment: It is working fine according what i want thanks peterm =) awesome but i have another question how can i group it by months i mean jan,feb? Do i need to post other question?

Comment: -1: This will work for the sample data, but if a policy has insurances that are both within and outside the policy dates, you will get duplicate policy numbers. Add this data to the insurances table to see this: INSERT INTO insurances VALUES (8, 3,"2013-03-01","2014-03-01", 100);

Comment: @CarlitosMorales Great! :) What column (out of four) do you want it to be aggregated on (by months)? Do you have specific month list upfront or it should be dynamic? IMHO a new question would be the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that you only get the last insurance if the policy has no insurances within the policy period.

```
SELECT policy_num, SUM(IF(p.cnt > 0, p.net_insurance, i.net_insurance)) AS net_insurance
FROM
(
  SELECT
    p.id,
    p.policy_num,
    SUM(IF(p.date_ini >= i.initial_date AND p.date_expired <= i.final_date, 
  i.net_insurance, 0)) AS net_insurance,
    SUM(IF(p.date_ini >= i.initial_date AND p.date_expired <= i.final_date, 
  1, 0)) AS cnt,
    MAX(IF(p.date_ini >= i.initial_date AND p.date_expired <= i.final_date, 
  0, i.id)) AS max_i_id

  FROM policies p
  INNER JOIN insurances i ON p.id = i.policy_id
  GROUP BY p.id
) as p
LEFT JOIN insurances i ON i.id = p.max_i_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Here is my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a712/42)

Comment: -1: The question doesn't provide exact requirements on on how exactly this situation should be handled.

Comment: Why is that a -1? That would just mean that this answer is potentially not the best solution to the given problem?

Answer (score -2):

Try splitting grouping from conditioning :)

```
SELECT 
  policy_num
  , CASE
    WHEN TRUE
      AND p.date_ini <= src.initial_date
      AND p.date_expired >= src.final_date
    THEN src.sum_insurances
    ELSE i.net_insurance
  END AS something
FROM (
  SELECT 
    max(id) AS latest_id
    , sum(net_insurance) AS sum_insurances
    , initial_date
    , final_date
    , policy_id
  FROM insurances
  GROUP BY policy_id
) src
JOIN policies p ON p.id = src.policy_id
JOIN insurances i ON i.id = src.latest_id
ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: I got ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "queries_pkey"

Comment: please be clariy your are creating values  and what is src??? Please apply your code with the question.

Comment: src is an alias for a subquery. the same as ") AS src". I had similar problem with sqlFiddle - worked when I run it once again. here You go:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6077b/44/0

Comment: Ok i will give your points back also do you know how to group it for months? like jan, feb, march

Comment: Well, you just add whatever you need in GROUP BY condition, add it once again on the same level (possibli giving some alias), and display it on the "upper level". try: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6077b/49/0